# Should I verify the posted contents after making a POST request?

Tags: rest, http, testing, bdd

I'm trying to write some tests for a web application based on HTTP REST API. I used to verify the contents uploaded through a POST request with a GET request. But I realized that I've tested a request using other requests. In other words, my tests depended on each other in most cases. Because of this situation, whenever I changed an API spec, I often had to change all the tests indirectly affected.

For example,

```
testGetA() =>
    expect(app.get('/A')).to.have.json('this', '{"foo":"bar"}')
testPostA() => {
    expect(app.delete('/A')).to.have.status(200)
    expect(app.post('/A', '{"foo":"bar"}')).to.have.status(200)
    expect(app.get('/A')).to.have.json('this', '{"foo":"bar"}')
}
```

`testPostA` uses DELETE, POST, and GET sequentially to test posting `resource A`. But if I change the spec of `GET /A` so that `GET /A` responds with `{"foo":"barzoo"}`, I must change not only `testGetA` but also `testPostA`.

Comment: Can you please state what testsuite in which language you are using?

Comment: @DaSourcerer Currently I don't have any web app. I used to use Java, JUnit, and Mockito. But this time, I'm thinking of using Javascript, Mocha, Chai, and [Chakram](http://dareid.github.io/chakram/jsdoc/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unit test of HTTP REST API, if `POST` request returns `200 OK`, I don't think you need to verify the posted content via `GET`. The purpose of HTTP API unit test is to verify the communication between client and server, not to verify the server side logic (like whether the posted data is stored in database).

Here are some detail reason:

1. What will happen if `POST /A` 100% works but `GET /A` works only in 90% case (due to some server side bugs). In this situation, the test case of `POST /A` will fail sometimes, which does not make any sense.
2. What will happen if server side logic of `POST /A` only save data in one global variable and then just return `200 OK`? (This behavior is wrong, as the second `POST /A` request will override the first one). In this situation, your `POST`-`GET` verification will pass, but obviously it can't guarantee any server side logic.
3. As test cases depend on server side status. Conflict will happen between multiple test executions, or between multiple test cases, which will become very complex when test case number increases.

In summary, unit test of HTTP API and unit test of server side logic are 2 different things. It is better to make HTTP API test only focus on communication (If `POST /A` request is sent in correct format, it should get `200 OK`. If the format is wrong, it should get `400 BAD REQUEST` etc.), and make server side logic test focus on logic.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I feel that I was trying to write integration tests through multiple layers. And as you said, I should recognize testing the network layer and testing the logic layer separately.